# will Texture declaration in method scope cause memory leak?

Tags: java, textures, libgdx

I wonder if this piece of code will cause memory leakage? because I still don't know when is a texture should be disposed. should the texture disposed in the end of method? or dispose it separately after unused?

```
private void loadAssets() {
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/controls.png"));
    TextureRegion[] buttons = TextureRegion.split(texture, 64, 64)[0];
    left = buttons[0];
    right = buttons[1];
    jump = buttons[2];
    cubeControl = buttons[3];
    cubeFollow =  TextureRegion.split(texture, 64, 64)[1][2];
    dpad = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 64, 128, 128);     
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, 480, 320);
}
```

and I don't really understand. why does there's still memory leakage in Java?

Comment: To address "why does there's still memory leakage in Java", even though Java has GC, but it still can have memory leaks (but technically not same as c/c++). It generally happens when you instantiate an object (directly/indirectly) and code maintains an obscure reference to it somewhere. That object will never be GCed. This is what we call memory leaks in Java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source of [`TextureRegion`](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.java), it retains a reference to the `Texture` but doesn't really take "ownership" of it - it's never going to dispose it itself.

Going by that, you *shouldn't* dispose of it at the end of the method, but you *should*  dispose of it when `cubeFollow`, `cubeControl` and `dpad` are both finished with - which I suspect will be when the instance itself is finished with. (That may or may not mean you need a finalizer - it depends whether you have some control over the lifetime of this object.)

Note that you don't need a separate field to store a reference to the `Texture` - you can get it from `dpad` using `dpad.getTexture()`.